# compilation problem/error while using an rxjs switchmap

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Hi i am getting an error in my code . I have an angular 5 formGroup and i am trying to use the pipe operation and switchMap inside.

However it give me an error. The following is my code snippet.

```
this.formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(
  switchMap(
      (formValue) => {
        console.log(formValue);
      }

  )

).subscribe();
```

the error i is as below

```
Argument of type '(formValue: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.ts(2345)
```

really appreciate any help
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return an `observable` in the `switchMap`. `switchMap` switches to a new observable and you can do it conditionally based on the previous value.

If you want to just `console.log`, I would use `tap`.

```
this.formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(
  tap(
      (formValue) => {
        console.log(formValue);
      }

  ),

).subscribe();
```

====================== Edit ==========================
I assume `this.generatePerformanceGraph(formValue);` is a regular function and it doesn't return an observable, then you can do it in the `subscribe`.

```
this.formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(
  tap( // you can remove this tap, it is just for logging
      (formValue) => {
        console.log(formValue);
      }

  ),

).subscribe(formValue => {
  this.generatePerformanceGraph(formValue);
});
```

Comment: what i am trying to achieve is form value is changed multiple time and use swtichmap to take the last emitted observable and call a function.

Comment: this.formGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(formValue => {
      if(this.formGroup.valid) {
        this.generatePerformanceGraph(formValue);
      }
    });            / this is the code i would like to use with switchMap